# TableViewCell - Custom Cell iOS - Content

Tags: ios, uitableview

i have a table with a custom cell. This cell have a label that i would like move in cell (if a condition is true). Why the position of label is updated only if the cellForRowAtIndexPath method for that cell is called for the second time?

This is the first question.

[image]
[image]

The second question is is as follows:
The custom cell contain a view, in this view i programmatically add images. If i have two sections in the table, after scrolling the table, the images of first cell in first section appear in the first cell of second section. Why?

This is the code

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

NSString *idDettCal = @"cellaVotoCalciatore";
NSString *idRiepilogo = @"riepilogoCell";
NSString *idTotali = @"bonusTotaliCell";

//Dictionary per Titolari e Panchinari
NSDictionary *calciatore = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];




if (indexPath.section == 0 || indexPath.section == 1) {

    foaVotoCalciatoreCell *cell = (foaVotoCalciatoreCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idDettCal];

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idDettCal owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }


    //TITOLARI
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        calciatore = [titolari objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    }
    //PANCHINARI
    else if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        calciatore = [panchinari objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    NSString *calciatoreStr =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@%@",
     [calciatore objectForKey:@"CALCIATORE"],
     @" (",
     [[calciatore objectForKey:@"SQUADRA"] substringToIndex:3],
     @")"];


    NSString *imgRuolo =
    [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",
     [calciatore objectForKey:@"RUOLO"],
     @".jpg"];

    cell.ruolo.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imgRuolo];


    NSDictionary *dettaglioVoto = [[NSDictionary alloc] init];
    UIImageView *imageIcona;

    CGFloat offset;
    dettaglioVoto = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_STM"];



    offset = 0;
    for (NSString *icona in dettaglioVoto) {
        if ([icona isEqualToString: @"AMMONITO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"amm.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_FATTO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golfatto.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_SUBITO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golsubito.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ENTRATO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"entrato.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"USCITO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uscito.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ESPULSO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"esp.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ASSIST"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"assist.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"ASSIST_FERMO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"assistf.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_SEGNATO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoresegnato.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_SBAGLIATO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoresbagliato.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"RIGORE_PARATO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"rigoreparato.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"AUTOGOL"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"autogol.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_PARTITA"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golvittoria.png"]];
        }
        else if ([icona isEqualToString: @"GOL_PAREGGIO"]) {
            imageIcona = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"golpareggio.png"]];
        }

        imageIcona.frame = CGRectMake(offset, 0, imageIcona.frame.size.width, imageIcona.frame.size.height);
        offset = imageIcona.frame.size.width + offset + 2;
        [cell.iconeDettaglio addSubview: imageIcona];
    }

    if (offset == 0) {
        cell.calciatore.frame = CGRectMake(cell.calciatore.frame.origin.x, 14, cell.calciatore.frame.size.width, cell.calciatore.frame.size.height);
        cell.iconeDettaglio.hidden = YES;
    }

    cell.calciatore.text = calciatoreStr;
    cell.votoIniziale.text = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_PRNT"];
    cell.votoFinale.text = [calciatore objectForKey:@"VOTO_PRNT_TOT"];
    return cell;

}
//La giornata è calcolata. Sezione 2 = BONUS e TOTALI
else if (variabiliGlobali.gioCalcolata && indexPath.section == 2) {

    NSDictionary *totaliVal;
    NSDictionary *totaliTip;

    totaliVal = [logCalValore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    totaliTip = [logCalTipo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    foaBonusTotaliCell *cell = (foaBonusTotaliCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idTotali];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idTotali owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.tipoBonusLabel.text = totaliTip;
    cell.totaleLabel.text = totaliVal;

    return cell;

}

else {
    NSDictionary *riepilogoVal;
    NSDictionary *riepilogoTip;

    riepilogoVal = [logForValore objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    riepilogoTip = [logForTipo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    foaRiepilogoCell *cell = (foaRiepilogoCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idRiepilogo];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:idRiepilogo owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }

    cell.voceRiepilogoLabel.text = riepilogoTip;
    cell.valoreRiepilogoLabel.text = riepilogoVal;
    return cell;
}



}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to post the relevant code so we can help you fix it.

Comment: I have posted the code

Comment: I have inserted images. The first one is when the table appear. The second is after a scroll.

Comment: Still don't get your first question. Which label do you want to move into which cell?

Comment: The original label position is in the first image (Buffon). The position modified is in the second image. The cell is the same.

Comment: Can you put here the code where you decide where you want the place the label?

Answer (score 0):

**First Question:** Which label? What condition? Are you talking about this:

```
if (offset == 0) {
        cell.calciatore.frame = CGRectMake(cell.calciatore.frame.origin.x, 14, cell.calciatore.frame.size.width, cell.calciatore.frame.size.height);
        cell.iconeDettaglio.hidden = YES;
}
```

You have to be more specific here!

**Second Question:** The reason that wrong images show up in wrong cells is that your cells are being **reused** by the `tableView`. Make sure to set the custom cell's `label.text`s and `imageView.image`s to `nil` right after `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` to ensure they are empty when reused.

**WARNING:** This is **NOT** a good idea:

```
[cell.iconeDettaglio addSubview: imageIcona];
```

Because your `cell` is being reused, and once reused, you'll see the previous `imageIcona` and add ANOTHER `imageIcona` on top as a `subview`. Make the `imageIcona` an `IBOUTLET` or property of your custom cell, and only set its `image` variable in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: First question: if i have not images under label offset is 0 and so i would like move label in the middle of cell. In  the first image for label "Buffon (JUV)" there are not images. Why is the label moved in the middle of the cell only after scrolling the table? For the second question i do not know the number of images that will add to view "cell.iconeDettaglio", so how can i make an IBOUTLET? My IBOUTLET is on iconeDettaglio.

Comment: @MarcoGrieco: I'm still not sure where in your code you're doing that, but try calling `[self.tableView setNeedsDisplay]` or `[cell setNeedsDisplay]`.
If none of these worked you can also call `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` on your `tableView` to reload those cells.

Answer (score 0):

**First question:** I can't debug for you, but without running the code, i can imagine that this part of the code

```
if (offset == 0) {
    cell.calciatore.frame = CGRectMake(cell.calciatore.frame.origin.x, 14, cell.calciatore.frame.size.width, cell.calciatore.frame.size.height);
    cell.iconeDettaglio.hidden = YES;
}
```

is never reached the first time because of this other part of code 
`offset = imageIcona.frame.size.width + offset + 2;`.

And after you scroll, this loop `for (NSString *icona in dettaglioVoto) {` is not performed because maybe `dettaglioVoto` is empty, and so the `offset` will remain equals to zero, and you will have it the way you want. But i can't be sure without you debugging your code to see why the `if` is not being reached the first time.

**Second question:** I don't think you are properly using the reuse mechanism for cells. So, if you are going to reuse the cells, you should use set `prepareForReuse` method in the cell code, like this:

```
-(void) prepareForReuse {
    // Your code code here: like clearing old images and text and/or setting new images or text
}
```

Also, it normally works better if you register the nib for the table view, this way:

```
foaVotoCalciatoreCell *cell = (foaVotoCalciatoreCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idDettCal];

if (cell == nil)
{
    [[self tableView] registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:loadNibNamed:idDettCal bundle:nil]
       forCellReuseIdentifier:nibWithNibName:loadNibNamed:idDettCal];
}
```

Comment: First question: if i have not images under label offset is 0 and so i would like move label in the middle of cell. In  the first image for label "Buffon (JUV)" there are not images. Why is the label moved in the middle of the cell only after scrolling the table?